# What roles to add to a Windows Server so that I can have a share disk to use in a cluster?

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2016, iscsi, clustering

I am adding the role - File and iSCSI Services - for clustering purposes

What I actually want is to add a `Disk Witness in Quorum` - a network share to be part of my clustering as per my picture below:

[image]

I am working on installing a cluster (windows server 2016), that will be 2 servers plus a `network storage`.

In the server where the `network storage` will sit, the first thing I am doing is to add the role `File and iSCSI Services` as per the picture below.

[image]

my question is:

Can I add only the `File and iSCSI Services`  role, or should I complement it with any other role, like `DNS Server` for instance?

This first time I did this, the server that hosted the `network storage` was also a domain controller, so I got a bit confused with this.

how can I clarify this?

Comment: I Edited the title.  I won't make an Answer yet because it's not clear what the issue is.  In general, add only the roles which you actually need for that server's purpose.  Be aware that Windows uses iSCSI Target to provide a share , and iSCSI Initiator to connect to a share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For having a server that provides shared disks to a cluster you need only the 
`File and iSCSI Services`

Plus you also will need the following `features`
that are needed in order to add a shared disk to a cluster (and that includes working disks and the quorum disk as well)

[image]

I will add the pictures with everything required up to the point that you need to `create the iSCSI Virtual Disk`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]